# Get iPhone device details using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect the specific iPhone/iPod touch model in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093899/detect-the-specific-iphone-ipod-touch-model-in-javascript)

I would like to get the Apple device model name/number like iPhone 4s(A1387) or iPhone 5 using HTML/JavaScript.
i tried using User-Agent which provides info like

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3

It doesn't specify model number or name. Only says that it is a iPhone.

Is there a way to get Apple device model name/number using HTML or JavaScript.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like http://www.handsetdetection.com

Edit:

[Read this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309998/how-to-determine-which-iphone-version-the-javascript-code-runs-on) Might be the easiest solution

Comment: Can you please point me to exact page or link on above sites.